# Which command should I use to enter a virtual environment on Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, hosting, virtual-environment

I developed a website (client and server side applications) on my local computer and am trying to migrate the website to the Internet. I am using a shared server environment from FastComet. When the user clicks a button, the server-side application app.js spawns a python file, but I cannot get this to work on the FastComet server. I get the following error:

```
Error: spawn python3 ENOENT
at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

The application is attempting to execute a file using the "python3" command. However, on a shared web hosting environment, Python is not installed globally, rather, a virtual Python environment can be set up. However, entering the virtual environment and executing a file using "python3" requires running a specific command first to enter the virtual environment. Which command do I need for this?

Answer (score 0):

The shebang line that starts the Python program uses the path to the virtual environment on fastcomet. Example:

#!/home/user/virtualenv/python.user.net/3.7/bin/python

That works. The program sees the modules I've installed with pip3 such as regex, pillow, etc. The only hiccup is that at least on fastcomet the python program in that environment throws a traceback that it cannot find os.environ['HOME']. This must happen after the program runs, because the program's output is generated (a file is saved). Hope this helps.